# How to use a CGFloat calculated in a method in another method?

Tags: objective-c

I am calculating the distance between the finger on the screen and a fixed point on the screen. No problem so far. I have my result in my touchesMoved method in my .m file:

```
CGFloat xDist = (x - ward.x);
CGFloat yDist = (y - ward.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
```

I need to use this `CGFloat` (`distance`) in my `viewWillAppear` method in my .m file (in order to set the value of another parameter).

How can I do that? I have been looking around this site but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: You need to use an instance variable.

Comment: Or return the value in your method and call that method from the one you need the value in; `CGFloat newValue = [self otherMethod] * something / whatever`

Comment: You probably mean calculated in `touchesMoved` from a viewController, and needed in `viewWillAppear` of another viewController, right? In that case, you need to give the value to the other controller in `prepareForSegue` if you are using Storyboards.